# Webpage snapshots on Internet Archive (Wayback Machine) link to future snapshots

Tags: web-scraping

How does a page (for example, [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20131007025750/http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/editorialpolicies.xhtml)) links to a snapshot in the future (for example, clicking on "Journal Policies" on the left panel leads to [this snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419102654/http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/journal.xhtml))?

Answer (score 0):

According to [USING THE WAYBACK MACHINE](https://help.archive.org/help/using-the-wayback-machine/):

> Not every date for every site archived is 100% complete. When you are
> surfing an incomplete archived site the Wayback Machine will grab the
> closest available date to the one you are in for the links that are
> missing.

Therefore, given the fact that the first snapshot taken on 2013/10/07 links to the second snapshot taken on 2014/04/19, you cannot necessarily conclude that if you visit the second URL on 2013/10/07, you would see the same page as the 2014/04/19 version.